# Can't access sharepoint site from local workstation. 

Tags: access-denied

I can access a sharepoint site from the server. I can't access it from a desktop client.

I can indeed ping the server, and there is a response, but from a browser trying to access the sharepoint site, nothing happens.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Can you give more information on your environment ? Authentication, Webapplication, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Even i have the same issue. Firewall services are stopped. Inside the server i am able to access the URL. But outside the server it is throwing an error. Appreciate your help in resolving this!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Chiatra What error is being thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure that the Windows firewall isn't blocking it on the server.  If it is Server 2008, it will block it by default.

If that is not it, you may want to be sure you are not using local computer accounts for your SharePoint service accounts.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a setting on the local PC hosts file. Or a Dns issue, can you do an nslookup from the client PC using the site name (rather than the server name)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure any firewall you have in place allows the port number you are using for your web site.  By default it's 80.