# Can't connect to sharepoint site from any other client, only from server

Tags: connected-web-parts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't access sharepoint site from local workstation.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6753/cant-access-sharepoint-site-from-local-workstation)

Sharepoint site is up and running on machine name.

So address is http://machineName:8888/

Works from server

Does not work from any client.

I can ping the server, dns is resolved.

Any idea why I can't access the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ruled out all the solutions we suggested on your other post? [Can't access sharepoint site from local workstation.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6753/cant-access-sharepoint-site-from-local-workstation/6754#6754)